# Remove the parent element if child does elements does not exist

Tags: xslt-1.0

In the below file, I want to delete/remove the CPT element if the attribute UMProductId has the value "Radiation Therapy".

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
            <AuthBatch SchemaVersion="1.0" InsurerId="123" Sequence="110" CreateDate="2014-07-10T02:45:02.317" AuthorizationCount="3">
                <Authorizations>
                    <Authorization EffectiveDate="2014-07-09" Id="12345">
                        <CPTs>
                            <CPT Sequence="1" UMProductId="Radiation Therapy" ChangeStatus="ADD" ResendIndicator="INITIAL" />
                            <CPT Sequence="2" UMProductId="Radiation Therapy" ChangeStatus="ADD" ResendIndicator="INITIAL" />
                            <CPT Sequence="3" UMProductId="Radiation Therapy" ChangeStatus="ADD" ResendIndicator="INITIAL" />
                        </CPTs>
                        <Program Id="46756" Name="test" ChangeStatus="ADD" />
                    </Authorization>  
                    <Authorization EffectiveDate="2014-07-09" Id="12345">
                        <CPTs>
                            <CPT Sequence="1" UMProductId="test" ChangeStatus="ADD" ResendIndicator="INITIAL" />
                            <CPT Sequence="2" UMProductId="Radiation Therapy" ChangeStatus="ADD" ResendIndicator="INITIAL" />
                            <CPT Sequence="3" UMProductId="Radiation Therapy" ChangeStatus="ADD" ResendIndicator="INITIAL" />
                        </CPTs>
                        <Program Id="46756" Name="test" ChangeStatus="ADD" />
                    </Authorization>  
                   </Authorizations>
            </AuthBatch>
```

But, in one Authorization, if all the CPT/UMProductId values are "Radiation Therapy" then, i would like to delete the entire Authorization itself.

Below is my XSLT, which is removing CPT elements but not the Authorization:

```
            <xsl:stylesheet
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" >

               <xsl:template match="@* | node()">

                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
                    </xsl:copy>

                </xsl:template>

                <xsl:template match="AuthBatch/Authorizations/Authorization/CPTs/CPT[@UMProductId='RADIATION THERAPY' or
                    @UMProductId='Radiation Therapy']"/>

                <xsl:template match="AuthBatch/Authorizations/Authorization[not(CPTs/CPT)]"/>

            </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Myoutput:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
            <AuthBatch SchemaVersion="1.0" InsurerId="123" Sequence="110" CreateDate="2014-07-10T02:45:02.317" AuthorizationCount="3">
                <Authorizations>
                    <Authorization EffectiveDate="2014-07-09" Id="12345">
                        <CPTs/>
                        <Program Id="46756" Name="test" ChangeStatus="ADD" />
                    </Authorization>  
                    <Authorization EffectiveDate="2014-07-09" Id="4567">
                        <CPTs>
                            <CPT Sequence="1" UMProductId="test" ChangeStatus="ADD" ResendIndicator="INITIAL" />
                        </CPTs>
                        <Program Id="46756" Name="test" ChangeStatus="ADD" />
                    </Authorization>  
                </Authorizations>
            </AuthBatch>
```

Expected Output:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
        <AuthBatch SchemaVersion="1.0" InsurerId="123" Sequence="110" CreateDate="2014-07-10T02:45:02.317" AuthorizationCount="3">
            <Authorizations>

                <Authorization EffectiveDate="2014-07-09" Id="4567">
                    <CPTs>
                        <CPT Sequence="1" UMProductId="test" ChangeStatus="ADD" ResendIndicator="INITIAL" />
                    </CPTs>
                    <Program Id="46756" Name="test" ChangeStatus="ADD" />
                </Authorization>  
            </Authorizations>
        </AuthBatch>
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance!!.

Thanks,
Ajay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- suppress Authorizations where all CPT nodes are "Radiation Therapy" -->    
<xsl:template match="Authorization[not(CPTs/CPT/@UMProductId!='Radiation Therapy')]"/>
<!-- suppress CPTs whose value is "Radiation Therapy" -->    
<xsl:template match="CPT[@UMProductId='Radiation Therapy']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```